# WebGL is not supported for Plotly by pycharm jupyter preview

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook, webgl, plotly

When I am trying to show a plot with `Plotly` inside `pycharm` I am getting this error!

**"WebGL is not supported by your browser - visit https://get.webgl.org for more info"**

Anyone knows how to fix it? ThanX

[image]

Comment: With Google Chrome for Android v77.0.3865.92 and Android's WebView Implementation select in the settings to disable Chrome to set-able Android System WebView would work, but with its v74.0.3729.136 there will be no support for WebGL, however you can visit get.webgl.org though. Plus, you may check this Chrome Extension method to pass this problem behind: https://helloworldhelp.wordpress.com/2018/01/13/how-to-force-webgl-to-work-on-google-chrome/